# How can I show slider in Activity?

Tags: android, slider

Actually now I'm going on with slider menu activity that is I need the slide menu in map activity in that I use **fragmentactivity** but how can I use slider in **fragmentactivity**.

what I need was when app load a screen with map activity in that I should slide menu in the same class how it is possible is there any way do it.

Here I use Google maps API V2 for map activity.

If anyone have any idea about this please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for slider menu which can be displayed when the action bar app icon is clicked or by simply sliding from left to write, try these below links.

1. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
2. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html